# Idiomatic way to store and operate on 2D data when access to indices is needed

Tags: clojure

I'm working [Day 6](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/6) of Advent of Code 2018, in which I need to store a 2D map of locations, and then do mapping + filtering on them based on their coordinates. I was thinking of storing the locations in a 2D vector, so that the indices of the vectors denote their coordinates, as this is how I would have done it in imperative languages.

However, the majority of the sequence operations only pass the element to the function, so there is no way to access the index of the element from the function passed to e.g. `map`. Yes, `map-indexed` exists, but it doesn't feel very clean to have two nested calls to it everytime I operate on the data.

I saw some suggest storing the index, or in this case (x,y) coordinate pair, with the element in the vector: `[[[0, 0] "loc1"] [[0, 1] "loc2"] ...]`. Would this be better than using nested `map-indexed` calls, or is there an even cleaner, more idiomatic alternative to storing 2D data and accessing the data with its index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific problem, the 2D nature of the problem doesn't really matter. So, I'd suggest storing the points as a vector of maps like so:

```
{:x x
 :y y
 :nearest-point :A}
```

and locations like:

```
{:x x
 :y y
 :name :A}
```

for example. For each point, loop over the locations and save the closest one.  Then, throw out the infinite ones:

```
(remove #(is-it-infinite? %) points)
```

Then

```
(group-by :nearest-point points)
```

and `count` the size of each group to get the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [matrices](https://mikera.github.io/core.matrix/doc/index.html):

```
(require '[clojure.core.matrix :as m])
(def A (m/matrix [[1 4 56] [5 2 8] [35 1 677]]))
(m/emap-indexed (fn [[x y] v] (prn [x y v])) A)
```